# Xdebug on Sublime 3 stopping only at first execution

Tags: php, sublimetext3, xdebug

Hi am running a PHP project on a laravel 4.2 framework, using Sublime Text 3 as an "IDE". I am not able to debug using de Xdebug client. It only stops on a few first lines, and sometimes it stops in some of the breakpoints I have.

It is very weird since it is not a consistent behavior, it just looks like at some point it loses connection with Xdebug. Some of my config:

```
{
"folders":
[
    {
        "follow_symlinks": true,
        "path": "."
    }
],
"settings": {
    "xdebug": {
         "url": "http://lab.rtve.ev012",
         "max_depth": 3,
         "launch_browser": true,
         "ide_key": "sublime.xdebug",
        "port": 9000,
        "close_on_stop": true,
        "max_depth": 3,
        "max_children": 32,
        "debug": true
    }
}
}
```

And this is the user configuration I have for Xdebug on Sublime:

```
{
"url": "http://lab.rtve.ev012/gestor-lupas/mi-lupa?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=sublime.xdebug",
"max_depth": 3
}
```

Can anyone explain why it doesn't stop on all my breakpoints?? I have tried the command xdebug_break() without success. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The first piece of code I posted belongs to the project configuration. The last piece belongs to Xdebug user configuration. Thanks a lot